# Source Index path of last row is being set to '0' when re-ordering row

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

Has anybody come across this situation?

When I am re-ordering the cells from the bottom most to top most I get a crash. These crashes happens when iSourceIndexPath.row becomes 0. I am wondering how is my iSourceIndexPath.row becoming 0 as this is the last row I am picking always. Any clue?

```
- (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)iTableView targetIndexPathForMoveFromRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)iSourceIndexPath toProposedIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)iProposedDestinationIndexPath {
    NSIndexPath *aReturnIndexPath = iProposedDestinationIndexPath;
    if(iProposedDestinationIndexPath.row == 0) {
        aReturnIndexPath = iSourceIndexPath;
    }

    NSLog(@"iProposedDestinationIndexPath=%d iSourceIndexPath=%d aReturnIndexPath=%d",iProposedDestinationIndexPath.row,iSourceIndexPath.row,aReturnIndexPath.row);
    return aReturnIndexPath;
}
```

Comment: What does the crash say? Show us the exception info

Comment: Do we need to reload the table inside - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)iTableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)iFromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)iToIndexPath ?

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to reload the table after cells are moved. You should do this apart from your regular handling of cells in it.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)iTableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)iFromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)iToIndexPath {
    [self.tableView reloadData]
}
```